# ListView selection behavior when layout has a background set

Tags: android, listview

In the app I'm working on, I have a textured background for the layout,
and also a ListView.  With the background in place, ONLY the portion of
the ListView items with text respond to touch---the blank parts do
not.  Remove the background, and it works normally.

Can anyone please A) clue me in on why it does this, and B) tell me
how I can keep the background and get the ListView working properly?

Thanks,
   --jim

Answer (score 1):

Find Whether those buttons are sent back to the image. If so bring it front.
Hope this helps better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989268/set-a-background-for-a-listview
<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130941/how-to-set-background-of-listview
Hope you can get it...